# simple matlab function (simulink) with if?

Tags: matlab, simulink

have written the very basic Matlab function on Simulink and would like why I am getting this error:

```
function [pos, neg] = select_output(err)
% if the error is negative , flow through the PID designed for negativ
% errors otehrwise positiv
if err >= 0 
  pos=err;
else 
  neg=err;
end
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign both defined return values for your function in every possible path.
`Output argument 'pos' is not assigned on some execution paths` tells you exactly the problem. The same also applies for `neg` by the way.

```
function [pos, neg] = select_output(err)
% if the error is negative , flow through the PID designed for negativ
% errors otehrwise positiv
if err >= 0 
  pos=err;
  neg = 0;
else 
  pos = 0;
  neg=err;
end
```

I don't know if assigning 0 to the variable that is not affected by your if-condition is feasible but in the end you need to assign both return values.